# Volume growth of balls II

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, measure-theory

Let $b:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ be monotonically increasing.
Call $b$ limit-tight, if
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\ \limsup_{T\to\infty}\frac{b(T-\varepsilon)}{b(T)} =\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\ \limsup_{T\to\infty} \frac{b(T+\varepsilon)}{b(T)},
$$
where $\varepsilon $ is meant to approach zero from above.
I invented the name, so there might be a better one out there.

Let $G$ be a group acting isometrically and transitively on a complete, locally compact metric space $X$, which also carries a $G$-invariant Radon measure $\mu$.

My question is this: Is the function
$$
b(T)=\mu(B(T))
$$
limit-tight?
Here $B(T)$ is the open ball of radius $T$ around any point of $X$.

Comment: Hm. On the definition: Am I right that the left limit is always $\leq 1$, while the right one is always $\geq 1$, so both should equal 1?

Comment: @Ilya Bogdanov: Indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a free group on $p>1$ generators and $X=G$. It is a locally compact complete metric space with its invariant distance defined by length of words. The invariant measure given by cardinality has $\mu B(T)= 1 + \frac p{p-1}\big((2p-1)^{\lceil T\rceil}-1\big)$ so for any $\epsilon>0$ one has $\displaystyle \limsup_{T\to+\infty} \frac{\mu B(T+\epsilon)}{\mu B(T)}= 2p-1$.